# Drawing graphics in C/C++ without a library

Tags: c++, c++17

Is there any way to render a pixel using C/C++  without using any external library. All mingw or gcc headers may be used.

Comment: Can it actually output something to the screen? I didn't use it, but I get the impression that it can't, and generating an array of pixels or an image file doesn't require any fancy libraries.

Comment: If you are so skilled that you can assert that library does not use any other library and still can show graphics on screen, why don't you just dive in the code and work out the rest of it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to draw a pixel by changing video memory map directly in a C program (without library functions)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28841555/how-to-draw-a-pixel-by-changing-video-memory-map-directly-in-a-c-program-withou)

Comment: It doesn't need an external library to draw things in its own offscreen buffers, it has its own algorithms for line drawing, etc. To make display something on the screen, it needs to pass through the graphics driver somehow, using an OpenGL context or some other OS-specific API.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot render images to the screen without external libraries, unless you do hardcore system programming (see for instance [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28841555/how-to-draw-a-pixel-by-changing-video-memory-map-directly-in-a-c-program-withou) fore more information). But you can easily render images that you can save as PNG/JPEG/TIF files, which is what I believe this library is doing.

Comment: Agree, but the _you cannot [...] unless_ part  confirms that the question is a bit opinion-based.